# Updating CSS property dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/U6gWx/1/

`$("div.ttt").css('display','block');`

I have some filter that sometimes empties the forst column which is float:left, when the column is empty I want to update the second column css style to float:left, basically want to align left if left column is empty. In my fillde I kind of have the high level of my code, How to do that using jquery, I am trying to do:
`if(!$('.ab div.ttt').css('display') == 'block'){` - to select if not any of the elements have `display:block` then change the style of .cd (second column) but it does not work, also I need to reset it once I get back the items in left column..I basically filter out the items in left and right depending up on the input.

Comment: Any reason you don't float left both columns? If the first column doesn't contain any content it will collapse, and the second column will shift over automatically.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/U6gWx/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ttt = $(".ab div.ttt"),
    cd = $(".col.cd");

$("div#test").click(function () {
    if (ttt.is(':visible')) {
        ttt.hide();
        cd.css('float', 'left');
    } else {
        ttt.show();
        cd.css('float', 'right');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/U6gWx/3/)**